# Detox selector failing after update to React Native 0.61.3

Tags: react-native, detox

There are 2 selectors in use in this test:

a)

```js
element(by.id('FirstName').withAncestor(by.id('SignUpScreen'));
```

b)

```js
element(by.id('FirstName').withAncestor(by.id('SignUpScreen')).and(by.traits(['selected'])));
```

and the second one, which fails, generates the following "query":

```
(
    (
        !(kindOfClass('RCTScrollView')) && 
        (
            (
                (
                    (respondsToSelector(accessibilityIdentifier) && accessibilityID('FirstName')) 
                    && (
                        (kindOfClass('UIView') || respondsToSelector(accessibilityContainer)) 
                        && ancestorThatMatches((respondsToSelector(accessibilityIdentifier) && accessibilityID('SignUpScreen')))
                    )
                ) && ((respondsToSelector(isAccessibilityElement) && isAccessibilityElement) && accessibilityTraits: UIAccessibilityTraitSelected))
            && !(kindOfClass('UIAccessibilityTextFieldElement'))
        )
    ) || 
    (
        (
            (kindOfClass('UIView') || respondsToSelector(accessibilityContainer)) 
            && parentThatMatches(kindOfClass('RCTScrollView'))
        ) 
        && (
            (kindOfClass('UIView') || respondsToSelector(accessibilityContainer)) 
            && parentThatMatches(((
                (
                    (respondsToSelector(accessibilityIdentifier) && accessibilityID('FirstName')) && 
                    (
                        (kindOfClass('UIView') || respondsToSelector(accessibilityContainer)) 
                        && ancestorThatMatches((respondsToSelector(accessibilityIdentifier) && accessibilityID('SignUpScreen')))
                    )
                ) && ((respondsToSelector(isAccessibilityElement) && isAccessibilityElement) && accessibilityTraits: UIAccessibilityTraitSelected)
            ) && !(kindOfClass('UIAccessibilityTextFieldElement'))))
        )
    )
)
```

And the hierarchy is:

```
|--<RCTScrollView:0x7f92ab6ee4d0; AX=N; AX.id='SignUpScreen';>
|  |  |--<RCTView>
|  |  |  |--<RCTSinglelineTextInputView>
|  |  |  |  |--<RCTUITextField AX.id='LastName'; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitSelected'>
|  |  |  |  |  |--<_UITextFieldCanvasView>
|  |  |  |  |  |--<UIAccessibilityTextFieldElement AX.id='LastName'; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitSelected'>
|  |  |--<RCTTextView AX.id='Typography'; AX.label='Last name'; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitStaticText'>
|  |--<RCTView AX.label='First name';>
|  |  |--<RCTView>
|  |  |  |--<RCTSinglelineTextInputView>
|  |  |  |  |--<RCTUITextField AX.id='FirstName'; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitSelected'>
|  |  |  |  |  |--<UIFieldEditor>
|  |  |  |  |  |  |--<_UITextFieldCanvasView>
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |--<UITextSelectionView>
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |--<UIView>
|  |  |  |  |  |--<UIAccessibilityTextFieldElement AX.id='FirstName'; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitSelected'>
```

Now, it's weird to me that the whole problem is around the `.and(by.traits(['selected'])))` part, which used to work before 0.61.3.

And, as far as I understand, both query and hierarchy have the `UIAccessibilityTraitSelected`... so... why exactly it is failing? 
What am I missing?

Some other tests I did:

Fails

```js
element(by.id('FirstName').and(by.traits(['selected'])))
```

Fails

```js
element(by.traits(['selected']).withAncestor(by.id('SignUpScreen')))
```

Works

```js
element(by.id('FirstName'))
```

Works

```js
element(by.id('FirstName').withAncestor(by.id('SignUpScreen')))
```